# "Renegatus": an active perfect participle from a non-deponent verb?

Tags: etymology, grammar-identification, participle

Several dictionaries' etymologies of English "renegade" trace it to Medieval Latin *renegatus,* an apostate, one who has denied his religion and gone back to another. *Renegatus* in turn is the perfect participle of *re-nego.* But *nego* is not a deponent verb, so its perfect participle is passive, as in *Jesus ter a Petro negatus.* But *renegatus* seems to be meant actively: one who has renounced, not one who has been renounced.

A quick search turned up just a couple medieval writings containing *renegatus,* and indeed they use it in an active sense. One example:

> Quarta fructus [partialitatum] est fidei abnegatio et proditio contra Christum. Conclusio est: quod omnes partiales Christiani sunt **renegati** et proditores contra Christum, et per consequens proditores Christianorum.

which I take to mean:

> The fourth fruit [of factions within the Church] is the denial of faith and treason against Christ. The conclusion is: that all Christian participants in factions are **renouncers** and traitors against Christ, and consequently betrayers of Christians.
>
> [*De Impiis Partialitatibus*](https://books.google.com/books?id=pc3J_oghDSwC&pg=PR53&dq=Bernardinus+Senensis+-+Quadragesimale+de+christiana+religione&hl=la&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1vrmXoMfkAhUEnKwKHcrPBWsQuwUIMDAB#v=onepage&q=renegati&f=false), Bernardino of Siena (1380–1444)

My question is: grammatically, what is happening with *renegatus?*

Is treating a non-deponent perfect participle in an active sense a normal but perhaps rare grammatical move in Latin (as in English)? If so, what are some other examples? Is it something peculiar to Medieval Latin? Should *-atus* be understood here as forming not a participle but a related noun, like *primatus* (primacy) or *triumviratus* (the office held by a triumvir, or the three men collectively)?

Comment: I just thought of a reason that _renegatus_ isn't formed by analogy with _primatus_ etc.: the plural _renegati_ shows that it's 2nd declension, not 4th. (Maybe a 15th-century priest would miss that, but Bernardino's Latin seems to be very good from what I've seen.)